# Application to manage videos library & show/ sort by video codecs being used?

Tags: library, video, database, file-format

For Audio, I use [Music Bee](http://getmusicbee.com/).

Would love something that can scan videos in specified folders and show a similar data view, and show video codecs of all the videos.

PS: I did scan them in a MB library, but it doesn't scan or show the Video codecs.

The only way to see video codecs is having to open each video with VLC and see its Info/ Media properties.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using ffmpeg to get the information is [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) which is also a command line tool but it focuses on extracting, (and for some file types modifying), the metadata from a wide variety of file formats, including most video formats.

There is also [pyExifToolGUI](https://hvdwolf.github.io/pyExifToolGUI/) which will let you view the same information in a GUI.

Both are:

- Cross platform being based on perl & python but with Windows downloads
- Free, Gratis & Open Source.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/engine/multimedia) for this. This SDK includes a MediaInfo class for retrieving information about media files. You can retrieve the video compression in a couple lines like this:

```
Leadtools.Multimedia.MediaInfo MI = new Leadtools.Multimedia.MediaInfo();
MI.SourceFile = "C:\MyFile.avi";
Console.WriteLine(MI.StreamSubtypeName);
```

This SDK is for Windows only, as it is based on the DirectShow and Media Foundation frameworks. It can be used via C, C++, VB6, Delphi, .NET (or any language that supports COM objects).

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company that wrote this library.